# RestSharp and NTLM authentication does not work if accessing API via hostname

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin, restsharp, ntlm

I am having a problem with NTLM authentication on Owin selfhosted Web Api.
NTLM is enabled on both server and client side. In client I am using RestSharp.

**Client**

```
 _client = new RestClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserAccessApi"]);
 _client.Timeout = 5000;
 _client.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator();
```

**Service**

```
var listener =
 (System.Net.HttpListener)app.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
listener.AuthenticationSchemes = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;

app.UseWebApi(config);
```

If I access this API via IP or Chrome browser it just works, while if access it through hostname or internet explorer, it does not. I assume this is related to restsharp using httpclient which uses IE engine, which in our company has some local/public networks security settings which are getting in a way for IE. Anybody had similar issue and have any idea how to overcome it without going the "Change IE settings" way?

**HostName based call header**

[image]

**IP Based call header**

[image]

**Fiddler log, 1st batch - hostname call, 2nd batch - ip**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm should help. But it's more like a workaround, as it'll be forcing Ntlm.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the restsharp to use the NTLM by using Cache Credential.

```
var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserAccessApi"];
var credential = new CredentialCache
{
 {
   new Uri(url), 
   "NTLM",
   new NetworkCredential(username, password)
  }
};
_client = new RestClient(url)
{
     Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator(credentials)
};
```

`NetworkCredential`, which is the default credential for NTLM, doesn't seem to be working for the case like this.